# How can extract reduced dynamics of a bipartite system from unitary evolution in quite

Tags: programming, quantum-state, hamiltonian-simulation, unitarity, qutip

Let us assume that I have a bipartite system $A\otimes B$ and an initial product state undergoing some evolution $H^{AB} = H^A+H^B+V^{AB}$, which is time independent. I want to simulate the reduced dynamics of $A$ only in `qutip`, and to do so I first generate the unitary dynamics of the full system as

```
result = sesolve(H, psi0, times)
```

where `psi0` is the initial state and `times` is the discrete vector of times.

From that I can extract the state at each time $t_i \in$`times` like `result.states[i]` and then do the partial trace like  `result.states[i].ptrace(0)` and obtain the reduced state of $A$ at the corresponding time.

Anyway, I would like to do that for all the time $t_i$ and having a vector of results like `result.states[i]` is. There is a nice and quick way to do that from the result object? Or I need to define a new function that takes the result.states object and that for me? I'm new to quit so I do not know if this exists by default.

Then,